# Get the names of the datagridview present in the form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I check the number of `DataGridViews` on a form, and then display present their names in `VB.NET`?

I have tried this:

```
For Each dgv As DataGridView In Me.Controls
        MsgBox(dgv.Name)
Next
```

But my guess is that `Me.Controls` consists of every other form controls except `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each _control In Me.Controls
   If TypeOf _control Is DataGridView Then
      MsgBox(_control.Name)
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is posted long time ago. In answer posted by @AadityaDengle You'll get `DataGridView` controls placed in form but, if `DataGridView` is nested in some other control (for example `Panel`, `TableLayoutPanel`, `GroupBox`, ...) it will not find it.

You have to search in all controls using "recursive search" way. Below is example :

```
'there will be stored names(id) of all DataGridView controls
Private allGrids As String = ""
Private Sub getAllGrids()
    'loop through all controls on a form
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is DataGridView Then
            'if control is DataGridView, then collect her name(id)
            allGrids += c.Name.ToString + ","
        Else
            'if control isn't type of DataGridView and have child control(s), loop through that control
            '(for example Panel, TableLayoutPanel,GroupBox, ...)
            If c.HasChildren = True Then getAllGrids(c)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub getAllGrids(cnt As Control)
    'loop through all controls on a "container" control
    'the search principle is the same like in getAllGrids on a form
    For Each c As Control In cnt.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is DataGridView Then
            'collect DataGridView name(id)
            allGrids += c.Name.ToString + ","
        Else
            'subroutine call hisself again with new control
            If c.HasChildren = True Then getAllGrids(c)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox(allGrids)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though both answers by @AadityaDengle and @nelek are right I will leave my code here that I think it's a little more structured.

> Note that this code does work with or without your `DataGridView` is placed inside a `Panel` or a `GroupBox`.

```
'Loop throught all DataGridViews in your Form
Private Sub FormDGV(ByVal Controlo As Control)
    If Controlo.HasChildren Then
        If TypeOf Controlo Is DataGridView Then
            MessageBox.Show(Controlo.Name)
        End If

        For Each Control As Control In Controlo.Controls
            FormDGV(Control)
        Next
    End If
End Sub´
```

If your `DataGridViews` are nested in a `Panel` or something like that you need to send the specifc `Panel` through parameter like this -

```
FormDGV(YourPanel)
```

But if they are not, you just need to send the form itselt.